# Powering ESP32 project from mains power

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, mains

Apologies if this question was already asked, but my searches didn't end up very consistent on this matter.

I want to build a curing chamber in an old small fridge and I thought the ESP32 board will be a good choice. However, I'm a bit stuck in the powering the whole thing, since I will need different voltages for the components.

The parts I will use will be:

- ESP32 board
- DHT22 temperature sensor
- 5V small humidifier
- 12V CPU fan that is laying around
- 1.3" TFT screen

Future implementation:

- power meter sensor
- load cell sensor

So, my first struggle is with powering all this from mains power, to keep it simple and compact. I was thinking to use the Hi Link power supply module to transform the 220VAC into DC 5V 0.6A for the humidifier and relays, and another Hi Link 3.3V for the ESP32 and screen (since the 5v Hi Link doesn't have enough current to power it all). But then, how I power the 12V fan? Or should I get a 5V fan which are a bit expensive and I already have a 12V one.

Maybe someone has a good scenario for my struggle :) It would give me hope that I can eat some good sausages in the near future :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the fan is probably to most power consuming device I'd convert your mains to 12V and suppy the rest of your peripherals from there. This presumes that you can build a small PCB holding the required DC/DC converters (12V/5V and 12V/3.3V).

Another approach would be to have a separate supply for all your different voltages.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. I was thinking of that but I already ordered the HiLink for 5v and 3.3v. And I see that the HiLink 220v to 12v has an output of only 250mA which is way not enough for the installation. Do you suggest another 12v AC/DC converter, more powerful?

Comment: If you need more power, yes

Comment: I think I will go with a 12V 2A power adaptor and like you said, I will use buckle converters for 5V and 3.3V. Thanks.